# Following A Question Via Email

Tags: discussion

This might be completely off-topic I know, but is there a way to follow specific questions on here via email?

Comment: Also see the answers on a related question here: [Can you receive instant email notifications from Stack Exchange?](http://meta.expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/147/can-you-receive-instant-email-notifications-from-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit your user preferences, there's an option there.

[image]

Comment: Cool, but would this count for specific questions? i.e. I want to follow only one of my questions, not any others?

Comment: Nope, it's site-wide.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks